# Extract integers from tuples stored as a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, integer, key-value

I'm trying to extract integers stored as a tuple as the value in a dictionary.

```
my_dict = {'String': ('123', '456', '789')}
```

Goal:

```
a = 123
b = 456
c = 789
```

I've tried

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    a = v[0]
```

Or by changing the for loop

```
for item in my_dict.values():
    a = item[0]
```

For both versions:

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Why the heck `int`? Isn't this a tuple?

I've tried a handful of other options I've already forgot but didn't work either.
I've been only learning python for a month by now, so I hope I'm missing something obvious here.

Any hint is appreciated!

Cheers,
Florian

**Update 1:**
My actual code. The last three lines are where I add the list elements as the values to my_dict

```
my_dict = dict()
for x in file_handle:
    if "string" in x:
        y = x.strip()
        z = y[7:-8]
        my_dict[z] = my_dict.get(z,0) + 1
    elif "date" in x:
        cleanedup = x.strip()
        titledate = cleanedup[23:-27]
        # titledate = titledate.replace("-", ",")
        year = titledate[:4]
        month = titledate[5:-3]
        month = month.lstrip("0")
        day = titledate[8:]
        day = day.lstrip("0")
        titledate = list()
        titledate.append(year)
        titledate.append(month)
        titledate.append(day)
        my_dict[z] = my_dict.get(z, 0) + 1
        my_dict_temp = {z: (year, month, day)}
        my_dict.update(my_dict_temp)
```

**Update 2:**
The application of this is, I want to check if the date stored as a tuple as the value in my_dict is within the date range of today - 7 days

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
margin = datetime.timedelta(days = 7)
for k,v in my_dict.items():
if today - margin <= datetime.date(v):
    print("Within date range")
```

I get the following error:
function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2)

When I change the if-statement to

```
if today - margin <= datetime.date(v[0], v[1], v[2]):
```

-> 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: The code that you show works. The error must be somewhere else; presumably, `my_dict` is not as you expect it to be. Please try to produce a minimal example that you can test *in isolation* and produce the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tuple unpacking to assign them all in one go.

```
my_dict = {'String': ('123', '456', '789')}

a,b,c = my_dict['String']

print(a,b,c)

#prints

123 456 789
```

If you'd want them as `int` you could something like

```
a,b,c = [int(x) for x in my_dict['String']]
```

Comment: they still need to be converted to `int`.

Comment: Updated the answer with an option which casts to `int`

Comment: Ok, that's a way I haven't though of.
The first variant gives the following error though:
cannot unpack non-iterable int object

The second this error:
'int' object is not iterable

Although, @Karl Knechtel has a point! When I'm creating a dictionary from scratch like in my sample code, your solution works.

Although the syntax of my actual dictionary looks exactly the same.
Going to add my actual code to the question.